# I work in a team which ____ the 25 company branches

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to fill in the following blank:

> I work in a national management team which *_*_ the 25 company branches in the country.

This management team is the one which every branch reports to. The team decides the overall mission, year plan and such. As for the blank, I'm thinking about the words such as administer, oversee, govern, manage etc.  But I'm not quite sure which one (or some other words) would fit in best.

Comment: Please stop ending your posts with "thanks".

Comment: What's wrong with "manage", seems to be pretty apt here?

Comment: Hi Mohit, I have used the word "manage" several times in the same essay. To avoid repetition, I'd like to choose another one.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with "oversee"

Comment: You might also want to read the accepted answer at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/asking-questions-about-synonyms -- or if you don't *want* to, then please accept a recommendation to do so [along with accepting an offered answer to each of your own questions, which helps the answerer and yourself to gain rep points].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion.

First decide the audience you are writing to. This will help you determine the "formality" of the vocabulary.   The following words are options that can fill the black.  If you already use "manage", go back and see if it can be replaced with any of these, then you will have "manage" to use in the most indicated sentence. And, when all else fails, use the Thesaurus.

> Manage:
>
> - Runs,
> - Directs,
> - Administers,
> - Supervises,
> - Oversees,
> - Operates,
> - Governs,
> - Controls.

Answer (score 1):

Some words worth considering are:
*supervise,
control,
monitor,
co-ordinate*.

Comment: And which one would you suggest?

Comment: It all depends on what you want what your constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be **manage** to fill the gap, but as you said, you want to avoid repetition, which leads me to use **govern** here.

I work in a national management team which **governs** the 25 company branches in the country.

The reason I would stick to **govern** is, you mentioned that

> The team decides the overall mission, year plan and such.

and by definition, govern means

> Conduct the policy, actions, and affairs of (a state, organization, or
>   people).

So, I think "govern" is the best fit here.

Comment: Would it be too formal here?

Comment: Govern sounds too much like government.

Answer (score 1):

*Administers* would be a possibility -

From OED -

> administer, v.
>
> Originally: to perform or execute (a task, office, etc.).
>
> Later also (now more usually): to carry out or oversee the tasks necessary for the running of (an organization) or the effecting of (a state of affairs); to manage, run (an operation, affairs, etc.); to manage the affairs of (an institution, community, etc.).